# Calculating power and energy of a signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I am a little new to matlab and would like to get some help on how to write a program or a function that can calculate the energy/power of a signal depending on whether the signal is an energy or a power signal.
Here is the program the I tried:

```
function [ ] = power_or_energy( s,t)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   s is the input signal
%   t is the independent variable

s2=s.^2;
energy=int(s2,t,-inf,inf);

if energy~=inf && energy~=-inf
    disp ('the signal is an energy signal with energy equal to ' );
    disp(energy);
end

power=limit((int(s2,t,-t/2,t/2))/t,t,inf);

if power~=inf && power~=-inf
    disp('the signal is a power signal with power equal to ');
    disp(power);
end
```

But the problem here is that when i want to check it for a function like

```
t=0:0.01:10;
s=sin(t);
power_or_energy(s,t);
```

then i get the following error:
*"Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of
type 'double'."*

So how to i actually calculate the energy for such signals?

Also the above function works fine with the below input:

```
syms t;
s=sin(t);
power_or_energy(s,t);
```

Please help me in writing a function that can be used to find the energy of any input signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Matlab function `int` needs a symbolic expression as an integrand, and a symbolic variable as an integration variable. In your example `s` and `t` are both vectors, and you can't use `int` in this case. If you want to compute the power or energy of discrete time signals, then you need to use the corresponding definitions:

$$E_x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x_n|^2\\
P_x=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^N|x_n|^2$$

In practice you will need to consider finite length signals unless you have an analytic formula for $x_n$ and some software package that can deal with the analytic evaluation of infinite sums. Obviously, finite length signals always have finite energy and $P_x=0$ according to above definition.

Comment: could u help me in implementing the power equation in matlab.I can do the energy part but could not make out how to calculate the power

Comment: @user94533: As I said in my answer, for finite length signals, the power is zero.

Comment: i meant for a signal like sin(t) which runs from -inf to inf .how do i calculate the power.also in case of a ramp function how do i do it using matlab.those are not finite length cases

Comment: @user94533: You mean a periodic ramp (sawtooth)? For periodic signals the power is $P_x=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|x_n|^2$, where $N$ is the period.

Answer (score -3):

Refer this link for calculation of Energy and Power of signal: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11202-automatic-gain-control